# jQuery mobile activity indicator not showing in android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I try to show activity indicator in my application. I am using `activity.js` for activity indicator. That one is working fine in browser and iPhone But its not working in Android devices.

I dont know why indicator does not working in android devices.

Here is my sample code for activity indicator:

```
function showIndicator() {
    console.log("inside show indicator");
    applyOverLay();
    var showIndicator = document.createElement("div");
    showIndicator.setAttribute("class", "activity-indicator");
    document.body.appendChild(showIndicator);
    $('.activity-indicator').activity({
        width: 5,
        space: 1,
        length: 3,
        color: '#fff'
    });
}

function applyOverLay() {
    var overlay = document.createElement("div");
    overlay.setAttribute("id", "overlayAttr");
    overlay.setAttribute("class", "overlay");
    document.body.appendChild(overlay);
}

function hideindicator() {
    $('.activity-indicator').activity(false);
    setTimeout(function() { $(".activity-indicator").empty().remove(); }, 0);
    setTimeout(function() { $(".overlay").empty().remove(); }, 0);
}

function loadhtmlpage() {   
    //location.href='#refillReminder';
    $.mobile.changePage("#refillReminder"); 
    showIndicator();
    hideindicator();
}

style.css:

.activity-indicator {
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 45%;
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provided the version numbers of the software you are using (like jQueryMobile) and whether you are seeing this behavior on the browser or in a compiled app with a web view.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following code to show the native activity indicator on Android..try this.. it may help..

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function() {
        navigator.notification.activityStart("App Name","Loading...");
     }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
        navigator.notification.activityStop();
    }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
        navigator.notification.activityStop();
     });    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to show the indicator in the **loadhtmlpage** method and add a handler to the **pageshow** method in the **#refillReminder** jquery page to turn it off.

I've used the jQuery Mobile default indicator and you try to show, in the same page before a long operation like an ajax call and hide it in the always handler.

Also it seems weird that you try to hide it rigth after you show it with that 0 timeout.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the default jquery mobile activity indicator as a fallback, using:

```
$.mobile.loading('hide'); //to hide the spinner
$.mobile.loading('show'); //to show the spinner
```

The component is very flexible you could use theme or overwrite the spinning gif.

More info here [Jquery Mobile Loader](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/loader/)

Answer (score 1):

Androide devices are slow

Maybe try to optimize your code here:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/

Answer (score 1):

Android browser is slightly slower compared to desktop browsers when creating elements and styling them using javascript. So for your case, the indicator might be taking time on loading in android browser but due to the problem i mentioned, the request is already completed within that time and the indicator didn't get a chance to show up, try to use css styling, add/remove classes and avoid inline css styling with javascript where possible.
For Activity loader try something like this:

http://jsbin.com/oPIyuqUk/1/edit?html,css,js,output

or try Jquery mobile loaders here:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/pages/loader.html